# Trying to copy function using .bind()

Tags: javascript

Here i am trying to get the if() statement used in variable bayern with the help of .bind() ,but all i get is 'your match is undefined'.

```js
     var club = {
    name : 'name',
    result :function(a,b) {
        if (a>b){
            console.log('Win');
        }
        if (a<b){
            console.log('lose');
        }
    }
}

var bayern = function (){
    console.log('your match is : ' + this.result());
}.bind(club);

bayern(4,3);// i gave it as a score a=4,b=3.
```

this is the error i am getting

```js
your match is undefined
```

Comment: You're not calling `result` with any arguments, so its parameters `a` and `b` are both `undefined`. `undefined < undefined` and `undefined > undefined` are both false, so neither branch is taken and your function does nothing. You need to accept parameters in `bayern` and have it pass them on to `result`: `var bayern = function(a, b) { console.log('...' + this.result(a, b)); }.bind(club);`

Comment: thank you @T.J.Crowder , as i accept parameters in bayern and have it pass them on to result ,i did get 'win' but the statement is  'your match is undefined' .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As T.J. Crowder already said in a comment, you need to pass the parameters `a` and `b` to your function `result`. Futhermore, you probably wan't to interpolate the result into the output, hence you should return it.

Following a working implementation:

```js
var club = {
    name: 'name',
    result: function(a,b) {
        if (a>b){
            return 'win';
        }
        if (a<b){
            return 'lose';
        }
    }
}

var bayern = function (a,b) {
    console.log('your match is : ' + this.result(a,b));
}.bind(club);

bayern(4,3);
```

Comment: thank you@alexanderdavide !!! it just solved it right !! but why didnt console.log worked like return did? thank you?

Comment: Glad I could help! Then please go ahead and mark it as the correct answer.

`console.log()` immediately logs the value when being called but you obviously want to make use of `result()` in the `console.log()` of `bayern()`, hence needed to return the value from `result()`. If you don't specify the return value of a function, it returns `undefined` which is what happened previously.